# How to lock speed dials on Nikon DSLR (D600) while in manual mode

Tags: nikon, camera-controls, nikon-d600

**Is it possible to lock Shutter speed and Aperture settings so dials can't accidently change them?**

Last time I was shooting with flashes I accidently moved shutter speed dial from 1/200 to 1/250. Small black stripe appeared unnoticed on all following pictures due to lag in wireless flash trigger (a piece of curtain). I want to avoid this in the future by locking SS and A.

**If it is not possible, how do you personally prevent these changes from happening?**

I am using Nikon D600.

(I know about AE-lock, but it controls automatic metering in [semi-]auto modes.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way you can lock them is to put a piece of tape over them. And even that's not fool proof.

I'll argue that the only solution to this is to simply monitor what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

Having had a D300 and a D800, ive not seen this as a problem, as Dan says, there is no way to lock the controls, you just need to be a bit more careful and keep an eye on what you are doing - do you not preview images between shots?

Yes a bit of tape would be your only option.

The reason for the black bar is not wireless trigger lag - it is because the D600 has a maximum flash sync speed of 1/200th - this would happen with any flash.

Comment: D600 has maximum flash sync speed of 1/250 actualy. You just have to change it in menu from the default 1/200. My wireless trigger is slow and can't handle 1/250 - it makes the black stripe.