# Is it possible to lock the shutter and aperture dials on a Nikon D610?

Tags: nikon, camera-settings

I have a Nikon D610 and often setup the shutter and aperture for studio photos and then for some reason one of the wheels gets knocked and I end up taking a bunch of photos with the wrong exposure.

It's quite annoying as I go through the effort of making sure they're correctly exposed in order to save time later and find myself adjusting a lot of them anyway.

Comment: similar question here: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/30734/how-to-lock-speed-dials-on-nikon-dslr-d600-while-in-manual-mode?rq=1

Comment: @Dragos Different camera, There is the possibility something has been added to the D610 (in the same way that a lock was added to the mode dial).

Comment: @connersz Sure, but it's a very similar camera and I don't see the value of having a variant of this question for every single camera out there...

Comment: Different camera but in the exact same series. What about updating the other one to cover Nikon D6xx or even Dxxx?

Answer (score -1):

You'll prevent it if you're attaching something to your camera to protect the wheels themselves from being knocked. As far as I know, there's no software sided option to lock up specific proprieties, aside the priority modes. Be careful if you're placing something in it, as it could turn to be sticky.

Comment: To whomever downvoted this answer, could you also explain why you downvoted? All the research I did on the Internet and the similar question here on photo.Stackexchange, suggests EXACTLY this solution.